# Find the problematic library in maven project, NoSuchMethodError

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to run a maven project in eclpise by "Run As / Java application"

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)V
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:556)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:281)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
    at com.allianzWebServices.ws.SubmitDocumentVersionClient.main(SubmitDocumentVersionClient.java:56)
```

So, obviously there's a library conflict. As I see the DeferredFileOutputStream has more parameters now, so I need to find which library is that it makes this call and update it. But it seems that the call comes from org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine which doesn't seem to exist in my pom and its dependencies or to appear at Dependency Hierarchy. I'm trying to solve this for days, how can I find the root of the problem? My pom is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jmimemagic</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmimemagic</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Running [mvn dependency:tree] prints:

```
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b25:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jettison:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jmimemagic:jmimemagic:jar:0.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.8:runtime
[INFO] \- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.3:compile
```

Comment: have you already run `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: You may have multiple versions of the same library in play.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I updated the quiestion, don't know if that helps

Comment: Navigate to the class, right-click an choose _Show In > Project Explorer_ to get the dependency. Open the `pom.xml` and in the _Dependency Hierarchy_ tab filter for that dependency.